# Coveo Facet Field Indexing Issue

Tags: coveo

We are using the Sitecore 8.1, and I have patched a field called categories in the coveo default Index configuration node to make it a facet.

```
 <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
<coveo>
  <defaultIndexConfiguration type="Coveo.AbstractLayer.CoveoDefaultIndexConfiguration, Coveo.AbstractLayer">
    <fieldMap type="Coveo.SearchProvider.CoveoFieldMap, Coveo.SearchProvider">
      <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
        <fieldType patch:before="fieldType[@fieldName='alltemplates']" fieldName="categories" isFacet="true" isExternal="true" isMultiValue="true" settingType="Coveo.Framework.Configuration.FieldConfiguration, Coveo.Framework" />
      </fieldNames>
    </fieldMap>
    </defaultIndexConfiguration>
    </coveo>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

After reindexing the web index, I see the categories as facet field on the CES server, and we were able to query it as facet field.
[image: With facet settings.]

Randomly, this setting is lost on the index server, and it is no more a facet field.

[image: Facet settings Lost]

All we have to do is to re-index the web index to make it as a facet field again. Can anyone tell me if I am missing some other configuration in sitecore ?

Comment: Which Coveo for Sitecore version? 3 or 4? Which CES version? Any CM/CD setup? If you have multiple instances, all your instances should have that field, since when a rebuild on your other instances will override this field. Also validate that the field is not duplicated in your ShowConfig.aspx (and the `patch:before` is unnecessary, the order in the fieldMap is not relevant)

Comment: It is the issue with multiple instances as you said. Iaddedthe field on the publishing instance and resolved the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to manually patch the config file to make a field facet, you can instead declare them in the facet/bucket folder of the Content Editor like you would do with Lucene: [https://developers.coveo.com/display/SitecoreV4/Making+a+Sitecore+Field+Facettable](https://developers.coveo.com/x/jIcdAg)

Then you would need to re-index yes.
If the field is "all of a sudden" no longer a facet, then maybe you have conflicting configuration files.

Make sure your CD share the same configuration file as your CM.

Cheers,
Simon